# Get scope which the request is originated in interceptor

Tags: ajax, angularjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

In AngularJS response error interceptors, is there any way to retrieve the scope which the current request is originated?

```
module.controller('myController', function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
        // This scope is which the request is originated
        $http.get('http://www.example.com/get', {
            params: { 'id': '1234' }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // ...
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // ...
        });
    }
});

module.factory('myInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(response) {
            // How can I get the scope of 'myController' here?
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access originating scope from factory out of the box.
Factories are singletons and it is not recommended to play with scope in it. 
Nevertheless, I believe you can pass the originating scope as part of param object from your controller.

```
 params: { 'id': '1234', 'origScope': $scope }
```

**update**

after following discussion...
I think instead of accessing the scope here. 
You publish the event from interceptor and have scope or associated controller listen it.

Refer this link for more information: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: The `params` object will be interpreted as query string in `GET` requests, right? Does it make sense to pass a `scope` into the `params` object?

Comment: I thought of that, well you can `delete config.params.origScope` before request is actually sent over

Comment: Basically as I said, it is not at all a good design to pass scope till factory or service.

Comment: Well, I am trying to retrieve the `scope` in a `responseError` handler, so the request has already been sent.

Comment: would be interesting to know why you want to access the scope in interceptors?

Comment: I am implementing a [token based authentication service with refresh tokens](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/). The service also [supports external logins](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app). I am trying to re-authenticate external login credentials in my interceptor. By following the tutorial, the author made use of `window.opener.$windowScope` for passing the authentication response back to the application. `$windowScope` is the `scope` I need.